# SAP crystal report throwing error

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

when i going to set the SetDataSource of sap crystal report then throwing the below error. but in same solutions previous projects report working proper. nothing showing another info about the error. i am using vs 2013 and SAP cr13 with wpf.

```
InvoicePrinting obj = new InvoicePrinting();
obj.SetDataSource(_invoiceListPrint);
```

**{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}**

please help

Answer (score 0):

I've researched this for other similar threads. You will have to post your code in most of them they ask that you do this. I believe that snip-it of code will not be enough.